# Kohana - Authenticating Users?

Tags: php, oop, kohana, kohana-3

I would like to get started on a simple project using the Kohana 3 framework (looks very promising), but the docs are a bit lacking in my opinion and would like some direction to get my feet wet and get me started. So I have a simple use-case question one that most every application needs.

How would you present a login form with a username and password, capture this, process it and return either fail or success? And how does it keep a user session (object?) persistent? I am new to Kohana with a Drupal background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's an [Auth](http://github.com/thejw23/simple_auth) module that you can take a look at to see how it works.

You're right about the docs for Kohana 3 being a bit lacking, but I think the developers expect people picking it up to be a bit more experienced and willing to look under the hood.

A few useful resources I've found for learning more about Kohana 3 are the following:

- [Unofficial kohana 3 wiki](http://www.kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php-)
- [Userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.kohana--------)
- [a guide to HMVC pattern](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/)
- [kohana 3 tutorial collection](http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/tag/ko3/)
- [hmvc widget example](http://kupreev.com/page/simple-hmvc-widget-kohana3-en)
- [source code for an example website written in kohana 3](http://github.com/shadowhand/wingsc/)
- [a blog module for kohana 3](http://github.com/kerkness/shindig)
- [a cms written in kohana 3](http://github.com/bluehawk/kohanut)
- Kohana IRC at freenode #kohana-

Comment: Thanks for those resources I'll check them out and take them apart.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/14/kohana-3-auth-sample-implementation-and-documentation/) tutorial. It is on using Kohana_Auth to authenticate users.